# Obtaining AKKA actor name from ActorRef

Tags: akka, actor

Is there a way to get the actor name from an `ActorRef` in AKKA?

I am referring to the name one would give an actor with:

```
val myActorRef = context.actorOf(props, "MyActorName")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name is accessible from the path:

```
val name = myActorRef.path.name
```

Similarly, the name is also in the path elements:

```
val nameAgain = myActorRef.path.elements.last
```